# Android studio XML animations explanation of position programming

Tags: android, xml, animation

Hi I cant seem to find an explanation on different ways to programm XML animation files in the android studio for example i can have a rotation set:

```
    android:drawable="@drawable/spinner_loading"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"/>
```

WHAT DOES THE android:pivotX="50%" MEAN? I know what pivot means i do not know what is the "50%" mean? 50% of what?

I know i can write also in dpi , but what is the most recommended way of writting to keep the animation scale the same for all the screen sizes that exist out there?